# Why does the TRUNCATE statement require the ALTER permission?

Tags: sql-server

I need for a certain user to be able to empty a large table, without logging cluttering up the drive. `TRUNCATE` is perfect for this. The user will have to have the `ALTER` permission, however, to be able to use `TRUNCATE`.

Any idea why `TRUNCATE` would require `ALTER`? Seems like the `DELETE` permission should be enough?

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/52828/what-permissions-are-necessary-for-truncating-a-table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `TRUNCATE TABLE` doesn't operate on the data, it operates on the structure of the table.

When you truncate a table, the data stays exactly where it was, physically, on the disk. Entirely intact. But the SQL Engine `ALTER`s the structure of the table to point to a new part of the disk where there isn't any data stored yet. That's why the operation is so much faster than a delete, where the data has to be "destroyed" within the structure where it's stored. There's I\O with `DELETE`, but `TRUNCATE` is a structural metadata operation.

*Edit:* Adding to the answer because of some good points in the comments.

To @alroc's point, if there is an `IDENTITY` column on the table, `TRUNCATE` will reseed, whereas `DELETE` will let the value continue to run up.

To @Bohemian's point, I should have prefaced this with "Probably..." because, really, I'm just guessing at Microsoft's logic, and I should have finished with the observation that, whatever the actual reasoning, I think it was a questionable move to require such a high permission level just to clear out a table.

Comment: I disagree with most of what you’ve said. The implementation choice of *how* the truncate is done is irrelevant to *why* it requires alter permission. Imagine if instead of doing what you say it does and it started an async thread that locked the table and ran conventional delete statements over all the rows; the effect to the caller is the same, but no special authority was required. However the implementation should never define the contract, in any situation. The *how* is not, and should not be, the reason you need alter permission

Comment: @Bohemian, that's funny, because I don't disagree with you at all. I didn't set the rules for the permissions, and I think it's moronic that a user can delete all the data slowly, but not efficiently without vastly too much other access. I'm also not making the argument that Microsoft had a _good_ reason for their decision, just that they had one.

Comment: It doesn’t “operate on the structure of the table” either. The structure remains constant. The data “disappears” (ie no logging!)

Comment: `TRUNCATE` also resets the seed of the `IDENTITY` column on the table, if one exists.

Comment: `But the SQL Engine ALTERs the structure of the table to point to a new part of the disk where there isn't any data stored yet`. you could use dbcc ind() to verify that. Truncate deallocates the data pages, it does not preallocate or point the table structure to a new part on the disk. In fact, the table does not seem to lose its first "unique/ non-mixed?" extent (the exact first 8 pages will be allocated after the truncate). The deallocated pages could or could not be used by the truncated table anew. This depends on the db's activity/quiescence.

Comment: ..and the timing of the cleanup process. You could manually call  sp_clean_db_free_space  between a truncate and data insertion to make sure that deallocated pages (from the previous truncation) are emptied and possibly be used later on by the same table.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you need `ALTER` permission is that zapping all data from a table is not an action you would ever need to do as a “normal” database base-using person/app.

Neither is adding columns or indexes etc. These kinds of actions are an *operational* concern and appropriately require an *operational* level of authority.

Comment: I _am_ going to disagree with this, though. Normal users flush and fill tables all the time.

Answer (score 0):

TRUNCATE will allow you to avoid execution of the delete triggers.
DELETE permission is not enough to delete rows without proper execution of triggers. I would say that was the reason why Microsoft decided to require more permissions for TRUNCATE than DELETE.

[Why do you need additional privileges for truncate table compared to delete? by SQLDenis](https://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/datamgmt/datadesign/why-do-you-need-additional/)

> When a TRUNCATE occurs, the operation does not log individual row
>   deletions, as DELETE operation does. The reason this is important is
>   because if you have a trigger on the table, in needs to be disabled
>   before the TRUNCATE occurs. Now you know why ALTER TABLE is required,
>   triggers need to be disabled.

Comment: this is very easy to debunk: `begin transaction; truncate thetable; select from sys.triggers where is_disabled = 1; -- no trigger is disabled  rollback transaction`

Comment: @lptr My point is that TRUNCATE will not execute triggers and that is enough to require more privileges. I agree that internally triggers are probably skipped, not disabled.